# Sitecore 9.0.2 Installation with SQL Windows Authentication

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework, installation, sql-database

We need to install Xconnect Xp0 instance (Sitecore 9.0.2) with SQL Windows Authentication, We don't have access to the SQL Server with SQL Authentication enabled.

Can you Please help what all changes we need to do in xconnect-xp0.json file to make it happen.

Thanks
Piyush jain

Comment: Please refer this question which is already asked and answered here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11047/sitecore-9-installation-using-sql-active-directory-user